# MySQL super privilege error 1227

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I exported my SQL tables and views from my local machine.
I tried to import it into my website's machine.
But I get this error: `#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation`

The error is given for this query:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `myview` AS select `my_table`.`id` AS `id`,`my_table`.`name` AS 
`name`,`my_table`.`surname` AS `surname` from `my_table` where 
((`my_table`.`name` = 'michael') and (`my_table`.`surname` = 'notyet'));
```

What should I select when I export my table and views ? To not to get this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove everything on the first line from the word `ALGORITHM` to `SECURITY DEFINER`, so that the query simply reads:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview` AS select ...
```

Trying to set the `DEFINER` on the view to `root@localhost` is a privileged operation.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent writing ALGORITHM and DEFINER, while I'm exporting the database tables ? From phpMyadmin.